# Hive FunctionTask Execution Error, return code -101: What does it mean?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, beeswax

I'm running a cloudera hadoop cluster that I installed using the cloudera manager.

I have a UDF that I have deployed and run successfully using straight hive CLI. This involves adding a few library jars to hive using 'hive --auxpath xxx' and then creating a temporary function.

But when I try to do the same thing using Hue + Beeswax where I add the resources and the temporary functions using the handy form fields to the left, I keep getting this error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask
```

I've searched over and over and can't find a place where the error code of '-101' is translated.

The logs I'm currently looking at aren't very helpful. Is there a different log with more info that I should be looking at?

I'd be really appreciate if it you guys could translate 'error code -101' for me or point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running a [search on the apache/hive repository](https://github.com/search?l=java&q=101++repo%3Aapache%2Fhive&ref=advsearch&type=Code), it looks like the exit code 101 comes from the `runSequential()` method in [`TaskRunner` (link)](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/3cc679cef292be4ee4eb0f1d9797027af84e7550/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/TaskRunner.java). It appears to be a generic exit code that indicates an error was thrown while trying to execute the task.

The version of Hive you are running is probably older than the source code on GitHub, so you could track down the correct source if you wanted to be sure. But I would be surprised if it was anything except a generic error code.